# How to disable bootstrap style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used `modal.js` from bootstrap, but after hiding a modal my div look likes like it has a blue border:

[image]

How do I disable or remove this border in .js/.css

Comment: Use firebug or such to inspect the element, find the style that has this effect on it and override the CSS in your own stylesheet.

Comment: :focus {
outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
} and how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers have a web development tool built in.

Chrome and IE have their own Developer Tools built in however FireFox has Firebug (which you have to install as an extension).

With these tools, you can "inspect" the DOM (Document Object Model) and see how the CSS styles are applied.

Here is a screenshot from Chrome (by clicking on a tag on the left hand side you will see which CSS are applied to it on the right side under "Computed Style" and "Styles"):

[image]

In your case you have to traverse down the DOM until you find the div you are looking for and then see which CSS selector is applying the border you want to remove.

Comment: I got this :focus { outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px; } and how i remove it?

Comment: see what CSS file it is specified in (should be under Styles > Matched CSS Rules) in Chrome's Developer Tools. You can then delete it.